# JAXB inheritance using substitutionGroup not working when unmarshalling

Tags: java, inheritance, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have 10 schemas under different namespaces, each with a complexType and associated element that is a substitution for an element called 'Report', for example:

`<xsd:element name="MyReport" type="foo:MyReportType" substitutionGroup="bar:Report"/>`

`<xsd:element name="Report" abstract="true"/>`

When I unmarshal an XML document that has all 10 reports in it, only 5 are found when I do the following:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.foo.bar");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
//get root node of xml
JAXBElement<ReportPackage> package = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new File("example.xml")));
ReportPackage rp = package.getValue();
ReportSection reports = rp.getReports();
List<JAXBElement<?>> reportList = reports.getReport();
//iterate through the 10 reports
for (int i = 0; i < reportList.size(); i++) {
    JAXBElement rep = reportList.get(i);
    ...
}
```

It does not matter the order of the reports or number of reports within the xml.  The same 5 of the 10 types of reports are consistently found. I've used the reference implementation 2.24u1 and 2.1.10 (JDK 6 version) of JAXB, both to no avail.  It appears that the substitutionGroup is ignored.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is it only certain types of subclasses of Report that are not unmarshalled? Are all the subclasses of Report in com.foo.bar jaxb.index or ObjectFactory?

Comment: It is only certain types of 'Report' that are not unmarshalled.  Each report type is in its own namespace.  For instance,
`com.foo.bar.report1.Myreport1`
`com.foo.bar.report2.Myreport2`

Comment: The same types (5 of 10) of subclasses of Report are not unmarshalled each time. Each subclass of Report has its own namespace, schema, and ObjectFactory class. The 'ReportPackage' schema ties all these different reports together, each being able to be substituted for the abstract 'Report' element. The ReportPackage has an ObjectFactory class that does contain a method `createReport(Object obj)`.

Comment: Here's part of the exchange schema, if it helps:
`<xsd:complexType name="ReportPackageType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element ref="bar:Reports"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>`

`<xsd:complexType name="ReportsType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element ref="bar:Report" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>`
Now, each of the actual reports are in different namespaces, but all have a substitutionGroup for "bar:Report" in the element declaration.

Comment: Check my answer and if it won't help, please edit your question and add XML fragment of problematic "report", JAXB-annotated class for the type of report that is not unmarshaled and JAXB-annotated ReportSelection. Maybe seeing that will help identify the problem.

Comment: Try abstract="false" - the base class is still abstract but the inheritance works - no XmlElementRef and correct SeeAlso annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create JAXB context this way: `JAXBContext.newInstance("package1:package2:package3:...")` where `packageX`s are packages where your ObjectFactories are.

Comment: Thanks padis.  This solution worked.  I had already tried this, but I had been using ";" as my package separator.